# Hooks in the render pipeline

Tags: theming, 8, hooks, caching

What hooks are there in the render pipeline in between

(A)
hook_entity_display_build_alter,
hook_entity_view,
hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view,
hook_entity_view_alter, 
hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter,

and

(B)
field theme preprocess hooks?

BACKGROUND:

I have a very weird bug that I'm stumped at debugging.

It occurs in my behat tests on Travis (Testy or Precise containers) but not locally or in production.

I have a custom field, on a comment type attached to a node type.
The custom field has its own formatter, which returns a simple #markup render element in some cases, somthing more complex in some cases, and nothing in others.

The failing test cases involve a node with 2 comments on it. The first triggers the formatter to return a #markup element, the second triggers a more complex element.

Locally and in production, all works fine and the #markup gets rendered. On Travis, the #markup is definitely generated by the formatter (I can track it through the (A) hooks above), but it disappears by the time the preprocess hooks are called and so is not displayed.

Something on Travis is going funny in the render pipeline. Being Travis I can't debug it interactively. I have rigged up a drupal_set_message/Behat combo so that I can see when hooks are called and print out variables.

What other hooks are there in the render pipeline before the field preprocess hooks that I should be inspecting? Any other ideas what I should be looking at? Could it be a caching issue of some kind?

Comment: What's in between is definitely the node template and there I would look first, preprocess hooks and twig files, because this is the place where most customizing takes place in a typical project.

Comment: Thanks 4k4. I tried switching the theme back to Bartik, the problem persisted. Turned out it was a caching issue - the output of the formatter for the field on the comment needs to vary depending on the revision id of the node the comment is attached to.